# Kafka retention AFTER initial consuming

Tags: apache-kafka, commit, offset

I have a Kafka cluster with one consumer, which is processing TB's of data every day. Once a message is consumed and committed, it can be deleted immediately (or after a retention of few minutes).

It looks like the `log.retention.bytes` and `log.retention.hours` configurations count from the message creation. Which is not good for me.

In case where the consumer is down for maintenance/incident, I want to keep the data until it comes back online. If I happen to run out of space, I want to refuse accepting new data from the producers, and NOT delete data that wasn't consumed yet (so the `log.retention.bytes` doesn't help me).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can ensure your messages have unique keys, you can configure your topic to use compaction instead of timed-retention policy. Then have your consumer after having processed each message send a message back to the same topic with the message key but null value. Kafka would compact away such messages. You can tune compaction parameters to your needs (and log segment file size, since the head segment is never compacted, you may want to set it to a smaller size if you want compaction to kick in sooner).

However, as I mentioned before, this would only work if messages have unique keys, otherwise you can't simply turn on compaction as that would cause loss of previous messages with the same key during periods when your consumer is down (or has fallen behind the head segment).

Comment: Too bad my messages aren't unique. But thanks, interesting idea

Comment: You can generate UUIDs as keys, and after processing just put back into topic with key equal to given UUID, and value of `null`...